# What is the difference between a = b and a = np.array(b) in the case that both of them are ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 case in here,

Case 1:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2])

def add(x, num):
    x[0] += num
    x[1] += num

    return x

b = np.array(a)
c = a

b = add(b, 1)

c = np.vstack((c,b))

print(c)
```

**The result is `[[1,2], [2,3]]`**

Case 2:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2])

def add(x, num):
    x[0] += num
    x[1] += num

    return x

b = a
c = a

b = add(b, 1)

c = np.vstack((c,b))

print(c)
```

**The result is `[[2,3], [2,3]]`**

The difference in line 11 when I just made a copy of a in 2 ways: `b = a` and `b = np.array(a)`. How should I get it? Can anyone explain it to me?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `b = a` - that does not make a copy, but refference

Comment: `b = np.array(a)` creates a new array for `b`, while `b = a` only assignes a reference so that `b` and `a` refer to the same array.

Comment: Oh, I got it, thanks a lot. It same as pointer in C/C++